# Como remover espaços em um texto sem transforma-lo em número?

Tags: excel-vba

Tenho alguns códigos que no momento da conversão para o excel, aparecem vários espaços e preciso retira-los via vba, porém quando eu uso a função trim a mesma os converte em número ao invés de manter como texto.

Exemplo:

1.1

```
Sub retirar_espaço()
    range("A1").value = worksheetfunction.trim(range("A1"))
End sub
```

Resposta:
1,1

O mesmo acontece quando eu uso a função replace:

```
range("A1").Replace what:=" ", replacement:=""
```

Gostaria de saber como realizar essa operação sem converter de texto para número.

Comment: Use o método de `.NumberFormat` ou a fórmula Excel `=TEXT()` ou para converter em String `CStr()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, as células possuem o tipo de formato "Geral". Esse tipo não possui formato específico, por isso ao realizar o TRIM com o valor da célula apenas com valor numérico (ex., se o valor da célula fosse `1.1 qualquer texto`, não haveria problema) o Excel converte o ponto em vírgula.

Antes de fazer o TRIM, você pode converter a célula para o tipo TEXTO:

```
Sub retirar_espaço()
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@" 'converte para o tipo "texto"
    Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Desta forma não haverá substituição do ponto para vírgula.